# Export GridView to Existing Excel as New Sheet

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview

I have GridView in my web application, while click the **Export** button the value from gridview to be export into new sheet in existing excel file accordingly as Day1, Day2, ...

Thanks!!!

Comment: did you checked the answers below? if you find a solution that worked, please mark it as the correct answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EPPlus Library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for this, here's a quick snippet on how to create sheets:

```
 string filePath = "~/App_Data/emptyExcelFile.xlsx";
 FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(filePath));
 using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi))
 {
     for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
     {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet;
        worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Day"+i, sheetName);
     }

     Response.Clear();
     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + "myExcelFile.xlsx");
     Response.BinaryWrite(xlPackage.GetAsByteArray());
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
  }
```

Hope this helps.